# PBS, adding job - job added, seems that it didnt run at all

Tags: cluster, pbs

First of all, Im very new to clusters and PBS systems. I was told to prepare a simple script (which I did):

```
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -o host_out
#PBS -e host_err
#PBS -q batch
hostname
date
exit 0
```

Then, I made it executable and I submitted with the command:

```
qsub job.sh
```

and got its ID (so it seems that the job was properly submitted, right?) But I can't see any answer, I mean, even the files `host_out` and `host_err` are not created. What might be wrong? What else do I need to do to submit a job?

Comment: with whom user do you run it ? 
Try to use as path /tmp/whatever

Answer (score 0):

Use qstat -a to check the job status.
If the job runs, one reason that you didn't get the output is the file was not able to be copied to your directory due to some cluster setup issue, e.g. .ssh key issue, permission issue.